What is the reason for not implementing for Vec<u8>
What is the reason for Vec not having hyper::body::Buf implemented in Hyper?
It is available for VecDeque as well as &[u8] (implementations)

Probably because Vec<u8> derefs to &[u8], so it's implemented for &v if v: Vec<u8>

That is true, however it is different for a body to own the data, as opposed to owning a reference. I wonder if they assume that it is easy enough to create a VecDeque<u8> from a Vec<u8>. Which would be a valid answer. Also it could be explained that users are expected to create New Type structs wrapping a Vec<u8>. In any case, I don't see a clear reason and it is not documented. Hence the question, in case there's a caveat or some other reason.

Probably more relevant is that you can wrap a Vec in a Cursor. VecDeque doesn't deref to a slice, so it needs its own impl.
